# SQL query to perform a lookup with transpose

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to achieve the following and to be honest, I don't even know where to start. We have two tables, Customers and Orders. I need to create a third table, which will have combined data, and displayed in a horizontal way.

Those are the current tables:

CUSTOMERS:

```
             Id           Email          Language  
Customer1     1       cust1@email.com       en          
Customer2     2       cust2@email.com       sp         
Customer3     3       cust3@email.com       ru
```

ORDERS:

```
        Id         CustomerId        Total
         a              1             200      
         b              1             300     
         c              2             400   
         d              3             500   
         e              3             500   
         f              3             500   
         g              3             500
```

And the desired outcome:

```
CustomerID  Email  Language  Order1   Order2   Order3   Order4   Order5   Order6
    1                           a        b        -        -        -        -
    2                           c        -        -        -        -        -
    3                           d        e        f        g        -        -
```

Each customer can have up to 6 active orders, but the logic can also be that for each customer only the 6 first orders will be listed.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this result? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything in your expected output comes from the orders table. I am not sure what you mean when you say "combined".

Comment: Sorry, this is just a simplification - let me add more to the OUTPUT table.

Comment: @StringTheory which SQL function would let me get the desired result in case this was all in one table?

Comment: Once you join the two tables(you may also do this after), you could use `case` statement but wrap them around `max` so you get one row per customer id. Don't forget to use `group by`. You should first try without using `max` to see why you need that. Here is some help

http://techslides.com/using-max-and-case-to-pivot-mysql-data-stored-in-eav-model

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* tables.  There is no ordering *unless a column specifies the ordering*.  Let me assume that `id` plays that role.

Then, you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select c.id, c.email, c.language,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then o.id end) as order_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then o.id end) as order_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then o.id end) as order_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then o.id end) as order_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then o.id end) as order_5,
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then o.id end) as order_6
from customers c left join
     (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by id) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
     on c.customerid = o.customerid
group by c.id, c.email, c.language;
```